# Unable to find question with tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

There is a tag called

> vb.net+sql

This I believe, should be two separate tags. Whenever I click on it or do a search for it, instead of searching for

> [vb.net+sql]

searches for

> [vb.net]+[sql]

Perhaps the admin's can search for the specific question and rename the tag, but I expect this will have to be done by the team.

I tried another query with a + in it and noticed that [c++cli] worked properly.

Comment: Known issue. There shouldn't be a plus sign in this tab. Here is a dupe somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was this question:
[if DDL statement fails whole transaction is rolled back sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677947/if-ddl-statement-fails-whole-transaction-is-rolled-back-sql-server)

Since stackql is down, I had to dig into the copy of the dump I loaded on my home server to find it. I expect StackQL up by tomorrow morning, but hopefully Monday at the latest; I'm moving next month and just haven't had time at home to fix it :(

Anyway, I fixed the question.  The tag should disappear on it's own now after some undisclosed amount of time.

Also note that this is still a bug.  We've just cured one symptom of the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Little bit tricky, but here it is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net%2bsql%20or%20vb-to-vb.net

Comment: wow, beat me by just seconds for an hour old question

Comment: But you already retagged/closed it, Joel?

Comment: I retagged it, yes.  It didn't warrant closing and I'm not a mod at the main SO site so I couldn't do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure we disallow tags with + in the middle now. I believe it might have been possible at some point in SO's history.